# Как получать DOM объекты из xml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Есть `.XML` :
 `<xml><at><file><a href='11'>Текст</a></file></at></xml>`

Получаю так `$xml->file`

Выводит ничего, либо чистый текст в некоторых случаях.

Необходимо же получить все,ничего не теряя. Простыми словами, получать как текст и отдавать браузеру...

Загружаю через `simplexml_load_file()`.Так удобнеё в разы. Могу доставать любой текст с любых узлов, но при доставании DOM - проблема.

Comment: А вы как-то загружаете `xml` в переменную при помощи чего-либо? Если да, то как? Отобразите это в вопросе.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  С помощью `simplexml_load_file`

Comment: А вы можете предоставить полный свой код с загрузкой и попыткой парсинга информации и его вывода? Чтоб было нагляднее и виднее что вы делаете....просто `file` у вас сейчас корень документа.  и `$xml->file` логично что не проходит

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Сейчас не могу.Там все валидно. Просто походу XML считает это как свои обьекты и их не отображает. Добавил полный код.

Comment: А еще, как я понял, вы хотите взять прям сразу ссылку `<a href='11'>Текст</a>` и отобразить её? Но так нельзя делать и не получится. Ведь это `xml`. Вы можете лишь взять текст из этого узла, текст из атрибута узла, а потом самому сформировать ссылку вида `echo <a href=<?=$xml->node["href"] ; ?>><?=$xml->node; ?></a>;` По-другому не получится. Да и в принципе неправильно

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Хмм,а если переводить в DOM?

Comment: Вы кажется не знаете что такое DOM. DOM – это стандарт W3C. Он определяет стандарт для доступа к документам, таким как XML и HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте разберемся по шагам. Конечная наша цель, это отобразить ссылку из XML именно в таком виде, в котором она там представлена.

1) Раз вы пытались сделать это через `simplexml_load_file` - начнем с него

Имея изначальную структуру `xml` в виде

```
<xml>
    <at>
        <file>
            <a href='11'>Текст</a>
        </file>
    </at>
</xml>
```

и при загрузке её в переменную, допустим 
`$xml = simplexml_load_file($someXMLfile)`, мы действительно ничего не увидим, обращаясь так: `$xml->file`.
Просто потому, что, как минимум, перед узлом `file` у нас есть еще узел `at`.

Если мы напишем

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
echo '</pre>';
```

То увидим структуру:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [at] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [file] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [a] => Текст
                )    
        )    
)
```

Что и логично (Мы не видим в структуре слова `xml` потому, что это корень элемента и `$xml` указывает на него в итоге).

Значит, чтобы добраться до узла `file` нужно, как минмум, обращаться вот так:

`$xml->at->file`, а добраться до ссылки: `$xml->at->file->a`.

Чтобы посмотреть аттрибуты узла, можно воспользоваться функцией `attributes()`. Например вот мы посмотрим атрибуты узла `a`;

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml->at->file->a->attributes());
echo '</pre>';
```

Получим:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [href] => 11
        )    
)
```

В итоге для того, чтобы получить нам ровно такую же ссылку, как в XML, нам нужно самим сформировать эту ссылку, добавляя при этом в нужные места текст и значение атрибута из XML.
В итоге получим в файле `php`:

```
<?php
    $link = $xml->at->file->a;
?>

<a href="<?php echo $link->attributes()->href; ?>"><?php echo $link; ?></a>

<?php
 // какой-то еще код 
?>
```

Лично для меня это более наглядный, т.к. понятно что и откуда мы берем.

---

2) Способ разбора, используя `SimpleXMLElement`, следуя его [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.simplexml.php)

Тут все просто:

```
// загружаем xml
$file = "<xml><at><file><a href='http://test.ru' id='test'>Текст</a></file></at></xml>";

// Создаем объект из файла 
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($file);
// обращаемся к нужному узлу и применяем asXML();
// asXML- Возвращает сформированный XML документ в виде строки используя SimpleXML элемент
echo $xml->at->file->a->asXML();
```

Если ссылок много, то, можно обращаться по индексу (или можно перебрать в цикле):

```
$file = "<xml><at><file><a href='http://test.ru' id='test'>Текст</a><a href='http://test2.ru' id='test'>Текст2</a></file></at></xml>";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($file);
echo $xml->at->file->a[1]->asXML();
```

Выбирайте.

**ВАЖНО!** Не забывайте. Вы **ВСЕГДА** можете посмотреть структуру вашей XML используя `var_dump` или `print_r()`.
Пример

`var_dump($xml)`

или

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Ну по сути `SimpleXMLElement` и загрузка файла одно и тоже.Фактически этот метод загрузки и делает то что в втором варианте. Дальше, я как раз правильно написал.При обращение к узлу file (`$xml->file`) не нужно ещё туда добавлять `at` так как PHP считает его корнем.Ну походу нужно перебирать ссылки и другие дела.Но так как у меня целые кеш файлы в XML,то там кроме ссылок есть ещё что-то...

Comment: @Maksym Корнем он считает корнем `xml`. Я  с самого начала это написал. Если бы у вас тега `xml` не было бы, то отсчет велся бы с `at`, да. Но в приведенном вами XML это не так.........`,то там кроме ссылок есть ещё что-то` - и что? в чем вопрос или проблема? Не улавливаю

Comment: @Maksym http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/rns7-ybs8    или опишите более детально (как я и просил с самого начала) какую вы XML обрабатываете, как где что куда зачем. Иначе всё неясно. Т.к. на изначальный вопрос я вот даже пример (ссылка выше) сделал в котором показана работа.

Comment: Помогло. Но для получения содержимого строкой достаточно использовать `asXml ()` и не перебирать каждый елемент...Исправьте

Comment: @Maksym Не исправлю)) Потому что если поставить просто `asXML`, то в итоге будет строка, но она будет выглядеть `<at><file><a href="http://test.ru" id="test">Текст</a><a href="http://test2.ru" id="test">Текст2</a></file></at>` то есть будет включать в себя все лишние узлы и они там тоже будут присутствовать... а нужно чтоб были только ссылки. А для этого нужно до них добраться

Comment: Так мне как раз нужно было получить все содержимое строки.И таким образом все дело получается с ссылками и другими  тегами. Да я привёл немного не валидный код, но суть заключалась в получение всего узла. Сейчас у меня все прекрасно отдает

Comment: @Maksym ааа... то есть вот в чем был а смысл, а не в том, чтобы получить конкретно ссылку в виде `<a href='11'>Текст</a>` не потеряв....ммм..... но думаю ответ мой не страшен...вам понятен, а другим поможет выбрать чисто ссылки. думаю это не критично