# Как правильно обработать узел и избавиться от мусора

Tags: php, simplexml

Есть `xml` - `<xml><mm><a href=\'1\'>12</a>11</mm></xml>`.

Гружу через `simplexml_load_string($var);`.Теперь вопрос,как получить все содержимое?Вместе с обычным текстом и ссылкой,например(следует учитывать что вместо ссылки может еще что-то быть).

*Если `$var->mm`,то чисто текст.*

*Если `$var->mm->asXml();`,то `<mm>содержимое</mm>` что не подходит,так как есть обертка в виде тегов `<mm>`.*(что-то мне кажется что тут без регулярки не обойтись...)

UPD: Если регулярками,то можно так `preg_match('/<\w*>(.*)<\/\w*>/', $var,$str);`,но...Это не правильно,мне кажется.

Comment: я не понял, так а что вы хотите получить? внутренности тэга mm ?

Comment: @ splash58 Внутренности,правильно

Comment: Анализировать, если внутри тег `a`, то писать `$var->mm->a->asXml();`  ...... я вам даже как-то раз показывал как-можно сделать и вы даже согласились с ответом http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487514/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-dom-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-xml/487616#487616  разве тут не то же самое?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Проблема в том,что все теги он не может обработать.Конкретно для каждого тега прописывать условие - напряжно.Я сейчас смотрю на констуркцию `->children()`,она вроде позволяет выгрузить все теги...

Comment: @Maksym children не выгрузит в данном случае `11` - text внешнего тэга. Так что, нормального решения, кроме вырезания в начале и в конце тэгов, в голову не приходит